# how to determine data type of arithmetic expressions involving divisions in c++

Tags: c++, division, integer-division, expression-evaluation

Have a look at the following programme.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  int n=7;  
  std::cout <<"n/2 = "<< n/2 << std::endl;
  std::cout <<"n/3.3 = "<< n/3.3 << std::endl;
}
```

output :

```
n/2 = 3
n/3.3 = 2.12121
```

In above example,

- Expression "n/2" have been evaluated using integer division.
- Expression "n/3.3" have been evaluated using real-number division.

What are the rules for determine which division is used?

Comment: Here are [C implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) and here [C++ implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) (C refrence explains it easier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arithmetic operations with two integer operands are evaluated in an integer context; arithmetic operations with at least one floating point operand are evaluated in a floating point context. (Beyond that there are more specific type conversion rules, but the basic idea is, if one of the operands is `float` or `double` it turns the other one into a `float` or `double` if it isn't already.)